# How to format a text in JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I need to display a JLabel text in this format.

```
Hoffenheim  1 : 0  Koeln
    Bayern  2 : 1  HSV
```

I just can't get this done. I've tried `String.format()` without luck.
Any advice?

Comment: It seems a `JTable` would be a better component to display this (tabular) information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use HTML. Read [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) for details. For example you could build a table, similar to the following:

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class StringDemo {

    public static void main(String arg[]){

        StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
        buff.append("<html><table>");
        buff.append(String.format("<tr><td align='right'>%s</td><td>:</td><td>%s</td></tr>", "Hoffenheim  1", "0  Koeln"));
        buff.append(String.format("<tr><td align='right'>%s</td><td>:</td><td>%s</td></tr>", "Bayern  2", "1  HSV"));
        buff.append("</table></html>");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(buff.toString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this did it! I had problem in this code with JLabel aligning to the left, but i sorted it with label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

Answer (score 4):

`String.format()` is used to insert content into a specially formatted string, not to display the string differently.  JLabels and other Swing components do allow HTML however, which may get you what you need.

```
new JLabel("<html><pre>         Hoffenheim  1 : 0  Koeln</pre></html>");
new JLabel("<html><pre>             Bayern  2 : 1  HSV</pre></html>");
```

That said, it looks like what you're asking for is to center your text around those colons, not just have them a given number of spaces away from the edge.  That's going to be a little trickier, but still possible.  To do this, you'll want to actually break everything up into several labels and arrange them in a grid (I find [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) to be very good for things like this).

Create six JLabels, [left, right, or center aligning](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AsimpledemonstrationoftextalignmentinJLabels.htm) them as appropriate, and drop then into a grid like so:

```
| Hoffenheim  1 | : | 0  Koeln |
|     Bayern  2 | : | 1  HSV   |
```

Obviously you can disable borders and so-on such that it doesn't appear to the user to be anything other than a nicely formatted bit of text.

Comment: Wouldn't the spaces be trimmed off automatically by the HTML renderer?

Comment: @MadProgrammer  I do not believe so.  If the spaces were trimmed from anywhere in a `pre` element, it would be incorrect behavior by whatever is rendering it.

Comment: They *shouldn't* be, but I haven't tested a `<pre>` tag in a JLabel, so I'm not certain.  Using HTML to center content the way OP's looking for though is somewhat asking for a can of works though.  I'd be much more inclined to do this though the layout manager - that's the "right" way to do it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry, your right, missed the <pre> tag, my bad

Answer (score 2):

Extending on from dimo414 answer you could actually use a HTML table

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);

sb.append("<html>");
sb.append("<table border='0'>");
sb.append("<tr>");
sb.append("<td align='right'>Hoffenheim</td>");
sb.append("<td align='center'>1</td>");
sb.append("<td align='center'>:</td>");
sb.append("<td align='center'>0</td>");
sb.append("<td align='left'>Koeln</td>");
sb.append("</tr>");
sb.append("<tr>");
sb.append("<td align='right'>Bayern</td>");
sb.append("<td align='center'>2</td>");
sb.append("<td align='center'>:</td>");
sb.append("<td align='center'>1</td>");
sb.append("<td align='left'>HSV</td>");
sb.append("</tr>");
sb.append("</table>");
sb.append("</html>");

label.setText(sb.toString());
```

While this is far more complicated, it gives you greater flexibility over the formatting.